# Storage data from HTML Form as a variable and print it in the html table (Python Flask?)

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

**So here's what i'm trying to do:**

- Static Website in HTML(just a simple table) [Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC8Tv.png)
- Admin Page to update text's on that website by html for (I'm not sure if it's good idea) [Another Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doWdC.png)

I was trying in Python Flask, but I have no idea how to storage data from HTML Form into Python variables. All I did is to use `{{ }}` in my index.html(first ss) and then I can edit content straight from Python Code, but it's not what I want.

**What i want?**
I want to make a form or smth like that which allows user to easy update text on index(first ss).
User has to choose which cell he wants to update and write a new content, then submit and that's all.

Is it Python Flask good idea to do it? (I'm pretty new in Python)
At the moment I'm using Wordpress+PostGrid plugin to do something like that, but editing the grid(first ss) is there so hard.
I'm stubborn that's why I want to do it on my self.

Any advises about method which I should use or language will be very helpful.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do NOT want to render a template of your table website, but change the HTML file itself, I have the following proposition for you:

Set up a Flask application to receive your request, e.g. on an `update` route (/update).

Have your admin website use a `form` that posts to your `update` route. Make sure to give your `select` and `input` tags the `name` attribute. For example:

```
<form action="{{url_for('update')}}" method="post">
  <select name="element">
    <option value="imptitle">imptitle</option>
    <option value="zaktitle">zaktitle</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="new_value"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

In your Flask app you can extract the information from the request by using `request.form`, using the same names that you specified in your `select` and `input` tags, e.g.:

```
@app.route('/update', methods=['POST'])
def update():
    element = request.form['element']
    new_value = request.form['new_value']
```

Then replace the element's value within your table HTML: open your table HTML file, read its content, search the element and replace its value using regular expression (you can read up on how to do that [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace)), overwrite the contents of the file with updated content. For example:

```
with open('index.html', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()

# new_content = ... (do your search and replace here)

with open('index.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_content)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your help, I did it this way:

Comment: Did it already :)
But I have another question, is it possible if I choose from List (for example "imptitle1")
to prepare area where will be display what actualy is printed there?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. Do you want to display a default value in your form in the browser?

Comment: No, no, no. I marked cell values with `<a name="imptitle1">VALUE</a>`. When I'm on admin page and i choose Imptitle1 from list I'd like to display current value for <a with name Imptitle1 from index.html

Comment: You could make another route that returns the current value of the element, if a GET request is sent; determine the current value by reading the table HTML file and searching via regex again. Of course your front-end would have to send the request and handle the response accordingly.